# SQL Inventory Count wont return item name

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working with our inventory database and I created a query (access 2002 format citrix run server) that counts all items of a type meeting a serviceability status and it runs as I had expected but when I try to display the item name *Equipment.Model* in the other table which is already left joined via the ID I get the error **Tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'model' as part of an aggregate function**. I think I would expect to get this if I tried to list something like an asset ID but this is related to the items I am counting. The trouble piece is quoted. The tables are quite large but they are basically the below
Equipment
|EquipmentID|CompanyID|Model|Description|TypeID|...

Inventory
|InventoryID|EquipmentID|Serial|Status|...

```
SELECT Inventory.EquipmentID, "Equipment.Model", COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM (Inventory LEFT JOIN Equipment ON Inventory.EquipmentID=Equipment.EquipmentID) 
WHERE Equipment.TypeID = 14
AND Inventory.Status NOT IN (4,5,6,8)
GROUP BY Inventory.EquipmentID;
```

Comment: I will also add that the quantity returned from the count is the same as the partner item query I use to get all items that meet the same where conditions which is why the join is there in the first place.

Comment: This question pertains to either MySQL or MS Access, not both. Please remove the inappropriate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Inventory.EquipmentID, Equipment.Model, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM Inventory
LEFT JOIN Equipment ON Inventory.EquipmentID=Equipment.EquipmentID
WHERE Equipment.TypeID = 14
AND Inventory.Status NOT IN (4,5,6,8)
GROUP BY Inventory.EquipmentID, Equipment.Model;
```

You have to use all non aggregate columns in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include equipment.Model in your group by clause